# Reinstalling software-center issues

Tags: installation, software-center

So here's the problem.

I was having a problem with software-center and I thought that a nice little uninstall-reinstall might just solve the problem. After checking that it was fine, I did it. However I am unable to reinstall the software-center.

I had performed two removal commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get autoremove software-center
```

When trying the update commmand this is what I got:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

When I performed the install command this is what I got:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Please help, I'm pretty new to ubuntu and I'm not exactly sure how to get the files for it to be able to install the software-center again.

Some more information: I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. Software-center does not exist at all on the computer as well, I've checked.

I read in another thread that I might have an issue with my source server, but when i checked software and updates it says im downloading from the main server.

Please help!

---

As per the suggestion to try:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This is what I got:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop
```

---

As per the suggestion to check the sources.list file, here's what I got:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list                

(process:3045): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(gedit:3045): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

The file that opened was blank. Checked if the file was blank and here's what I got:

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list
ls: cannot access /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory
```

I guess its safe to assume that its empty?

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Doesn't work. edited above post with what I got.

Comment: Please copy the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file using http://pastebin.com/ and post us a link to it as a comment here

Comment: That's the thing though, after I got the above errors there, gedit opened up and the sources.list file was blank.

Comment: Try `sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to confirm it is really blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you don't have an `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, so `apt-get` don't know where to get your packages from.

Create the file using `sudo`, then either paste [this content](http://pastebin.com/cNGPEdhu), or use [this online sources.list generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php) to customize it -- Choose your country and distro version, then what branches you want. I recommend only the main branches, security updates and recommended updates. Be extra careful before chosing 3rd-party or proposed pre-release updates.

After creating the file, perform `apt-get update` and then install your package.

Comment: I realized that I never accepted an answer here. My circumstances are entirely changed, and I think I ended up reinstalling my system, but I will select this as it is a reasonable answer to try, given what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Software Center is part of the main Ubuntu repository.

First of all, let's check the [official info about the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/software-center): We can see there is a version of it for 13.04 (see "rarin on the top right area). We can see all the depencies as well.

Now we have two options:

#### Manual install (not recommended)

You can click the download link at the bottom of the page. From there you can pick from a list of mirrors, download the `.deb` file and double click on it to install the file.
However, this is not the best option as files installed manually won't usually be updated automatically.

Your best option is the following, even suggested on the download page

#### Add the repository to your list

1) Check the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. The first few lines should be similar to:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://SOMETHING/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://SOMETHING/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

My version is 12.04 (codename "precise"), yours should read "raring" instead.

Now you perform `apt-get update` again, then try installing, it should work.

Comment: So i tried to get the sources.list file, using the 'sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list' but i got an interesting reading and the file was blank. Updating the top with what I found

Comment: @NotCras Open the terminal and type these two commands, paste its outputs on your question:  `sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Did it and I would say it seems that its either empty or doesn't exist. Added the output into the question.